# Unable to start subversion using Launchctl

Tags: macos, svn, launchd

I'm trying to use Launchctl to launch svnserve process but I keep getting an error saying "no plist was returned for:/Library/LaunchAgents/org.tigris.subversion.svnserve.plist". This is where svnserve is /opt/local/bin/svnserve and this is the plist file
Any thoughts what might be wrong here ?

```
<dict>
  <key>Disabled</key>
  <false/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>org.tigris.subversion.svnserve</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
      <string>/opt/local/bin/svnserve</string>
      <string>--inetd</string>
      <string>--root=/Users/Sunit/Repositories</string>
  </array>
  <key>ServiceDescription</key>
  <string>SVN Version Control System/string>
  <key>Sockets</key>
  <dict>
    <key>Listeners</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>SockFamily</key>
        <string>IPv4</string>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>svn</string>
        <key>SockType</key>
        <string>stream</string>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>SockFamily</key>
        <string>IPv6</string>
        <key>SockServiceName</key>
        <string>svn</string>
        <key>SockType</key>
        <string>stream</string>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
```

Comment: SJMAC:~ sunit$ sudo launchctl load  /Library/LaunchAgents/org.tigris.subversion.svnserve.plist
launchctl: propertyList is NULL
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchAgents/org.tigris.subversion.svnserve.plist
launchctl: no plist was returned for: /Library/LaunchAgents/org.tigris.subversion.svnserve.plist
nothing found to load

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That file is not valid XML - you don't close the `<string>` tag on line 13 correctly, and you never close the outermost `<dict>` tag.

You can use `plutil -lint` to check a property list's validity, or simply use Property List Editor, Xcode or a third-party property list editor to construct the property list graphically.

Comment: Thanks this I did find it already. Also is there a way to access this from an XP VM. I tried sv://sjmac but that timed out.

Comment: also ps aux | grep svn does not returns this
sunit    71889   0.0  0.0   599780    428 s000  R+    6:08PM   0:00.00 grep svn
 which it not correct !

Comment: Wow, thanks heaps for that.  `plutil -lint` is very handy indeed!